Child node attribute is null
I have a scene 'DragonSelector' which extends Area2D. The scene has a Sprite2D node called 'DragonSprite'.
DragonSelector.gd
class_name DragonSelector
extends Area2D

@onready var dragon_sprite = $DragonSprite

func _ready():
    pass 

func _process(delta):
    pass

func set_texture(dragon_texture: Texture):
    dragon_sprite.Texture = dragon_texture

I want to instantiate this scene in 'Main' scene and set the Texture on 'DragonSprite' in runtime.
Main.gd
class_name Main
extends Node2D

var dragon_selector_scene = preload("res://dragon_selector/dragon_selector.tscn")

func _ready():
    var dragon_selector_instance = dragon_selector_scene.instantiate()
    var texture = preload("res://dragon/flying_dragon-gold.png")
    dragon_selector_instance.set_texture(texture)
    add_child(dragon_selector_instance)
    dragon_selector_instance.position = Vector2(100, 100) 
    
func _process(delta):
    pass

This yields an error: Invalid set index 'Texture' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'CompressedTexture2D'. This is associated with the texture assignment line in set_texture:

To validate that the texture is where I think it is, I changed function set_texture to load the texture directly from within DragonSelector.gd:
func set_texture(dragon_texture: Texture):
    dragon_sprite.Texture = preload("res://dragon/flying_dragon-gold.png")
    #dragon_sprite.Texture = dragon_texture

This works as expected. Apologies for the vague title, I have no idea what to refer this to. Suggestions for correction are welcome.
Using godot 4.2.1

"T" should be lowercase like this: dragon_sprite.texture = dragon_texture

I tried both ways with the same result, both for the method that woks and the one that doesn't. Seems like godot isn't always fussed about case management.

No I'm pretty sure godot is case sensitive, for e.g. when I attached a script to a Sprite2D and tried to assign a image as self.Texture = ... it gives the error Invalid set index 'Texture' (on base: 'Sprite2D (sprite.gd)') with value of type 'CompressedTexture2D'. which leads to me to your other problem on base: Nil I'm guessing dragon_sprite has a null value, you might want to print() and check it

The issue is that I was trying to set the texture before I added the dragon_selector to the scene tree:
var texture = preload("res://dragon/flying_dragon-gold.png")
dragon_selector_instance.set_texture(texture)
add_child(dragon_selector_instance)

Inside the dragon_selector script, dragon_sprite is only available after Ready() was executed which only happens after dragon_selector is added. Switching the order solved the issue.

Try this:
...

func _ready():
    var dragon_selector_instance = dragon_selector_scene.instantiate()
    var texture = preload("res://dragon/flying_dragon-gold.png")
    dragon_selector_instance.dragon_sprite.set_texture(texture) # changed here
    ...

Since the dragon_selector_instance is of type Area2D and within it you have a variable named dragon_sprite which is the actual node of which you'd want to change the texture
